# File name look the same but is different after copying

Tags: linux, encoding, terminal, console, filenames

My file names look the same but they are not.

I copied `many_img/` from Debian1 to OS X, then from OS X to Debian2 (for maintenance purpose) with using  `rsync -a -e ssh` on each step to preserve everything.

If i do  `ls many_img/img1/*` i get visually the same output on Debian1 and Debian2 :

```
prévisionnel.jpg
```

But somehow, `ls many_img/img1/* | od -c` gives different results:

On Debian1:

```
0000000   p   r 303 251   v   i   s   i   o   n   n   e   l  .   j   p
0000020   g  \n
```

On Debian2:

```
0000000   p   r   e 314 201   v   i   s   i   o   n   n   e   l  .   j
0000020   p   g  \n
```

Thus my web app on Debian2 cannot match the picture in the file system with filename in database.

i thought maybe i need to change file encoding, but it looks like it's already utf-8 on every OS:

```
convmv --notest -f iso-8859-15 -t utf8 many_img/img1/*
```

Returns:

```
Skipping, already UTF-8
```

Is there a command to get back all my 40 thousands file names like on my Debian 1 from my Debian 2 (without transfering all again) ?
I am confused if it is a file name encoding problem or anything else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finaly found command line conversion tools i was looking for (thanks @Mark for setting me on the right track !)

Ok, i didn't know OS X was encoding file names under the hood with a different UTF-8 Normalization.

- It appears OS X is using Unicode Normalization Form D (NFD)
- while Linux OS are using Unicode Normalization Form C (NFC)

HSF+ file system encode every single file name character in UTF-16.
Unicode characters are Decomposed on OS X versus Precomposed on Linux OS.

`é` for instance (Latin small letter e with acute accent), is technically a `(U+00E9)` character on Linux
and is decomposed into a base letter "e" `(U+0065)` and an acute accent `(U+0301)` in its decomposed form (NFD) on OS X.

### Now about conversion tools:

1. This command executed from Linux OS will convert file name from NFD
   to NFC:

   **convmv --notest --nfc -f utf8 -t utf8 /path/to/my/file**
2. This command executed from OS X will rsync over ssh with NFD to NDC
   on the fly conversion:

   **rsync -a --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8 -e ssh path/to/my/local/directory/* user@destinationip:/remote/path/**

I tested the two methods and it works like a charm.

**Note**:

`--iconv` option is only available with rsync V3 whereas OS X provides an old 2.6.9 version by default so you'll need to update it first.

Typically to check and upgrade :

```
rsync --version
brew install rsync
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 2):

The first filename contains the single character [`é`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) while the second contains a simple `e` followed by the combining character [`́` (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm). They're both valid Unicode, they're just [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) differently. It appears the OS normalized the filename as it created the file.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, Thumb up, you're 100% right and it helped me to focus and look further. After a couple of hours googling, i finaly found the command line tools i need to convert filenames accordingly.